# How can I get Geforce gt630m working?

Tags: 12.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics

I have this hp 5008tx laptop:

- Core i5 (2nd Generation) 2450M
- 6 GB RAM DDR3
- Mobile Intel HM77 Express
- NVIDIA GeForce 630M 2 GB DDR3

**I'd just installed 12.04lts 64-bit (kernel 3.2.0-23-generic)**

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia

Answer (score 0):

As the previous responder wrote, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia is a good article to read on the subject. At the moment, however, I recommend the closed-source drivers for your use, as the Nouveau drivers still need some work to fully utilize the power of the GPU, and cannot provide 3D acceleration.